# Anchor an ImageView to corner of another ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, imageview

[image: Two image views on each other]

How to anchor an ImageView to bottom right corner of another ImageView like the ones in the above picture (1-man and 2-pencil)

I am using retrofit to load my sources as oval into ImageViews

I do this :

```
   Glide.with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(model)
        .fitCenter()
        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
        .into(object : BitmapImageViewTarget(this) {
            override fun setResource(resource: Bitmap?) {
                setImageDrawable(
                    resource?.run {
                        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(
                            resources,
                            if (borderSize > 0) {
                                createBitmapWithBorder(borderSize, borderColor)
                            } else {
                                this
                            }
                        ).apply {
                            isCircular = true
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        })
```

Comment: @Sajjad  I would have two imageView And I can do oval imageView But I can not create two imageView which look like in screen

Comment: @Sajjad Yes I would like do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Base concept

To build such layout you can use for example `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Using `RelativeLayout` you can build such structure:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#00f" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#f0f" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which should look like there:
[image]

## Small circle

For smaller circle (grey one) you can use only one  `ImageView`. Just set light background - as `background` and pen icon - as `src`.

**1) For `ImageView` `background` you have to create new drawable with two `shape`s**. First ont is for white border around, second it's just light gray background.

You can set padding second shape (here, in example, there is `5dp`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#CACACA" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**2) As icon you can use drawable (e.g. vector) or just image and set it as `src`**

After this point it should look like there:

[image]

3) Set `padding` in `ImageView` to scale your (pen) icon correctly:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/small_circle_background"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/small_circle_icon" />
```

## Big circle

Best approach is to use some library like Picasso or Glide.

For Glide, you can use `CircleTransform()` to crop received image in to circle. When loading image you can just use `transform()` method:

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(URL)
    .transform(new CircleTransform(context))
    .into(imageView);
```

When `CircleTransform` is:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.BitmapPool;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapTransformation;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class CircleTransform extends BitmapTransformation {

    @Override protected Bitmap transform(@NotNull BitmapPool pool, @NotNull Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
        return circleCrop(pool, toTransform);
    }

    private static Bitmap circleCrop(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap source) {
        if (source == null) return null;

        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squared = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);

        Bitmap result = pool.get(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(squared, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        float r = size / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDiskCacheKey(@NonNull MessageDigest messageDigest) {

    }
}
```

## Final result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/first_image"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/second"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```